# Como redimensionar aplicação coonforme o monitor?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho uma aplicação que abre um `JFrame`, tendo na parte superior um `JMenuBar`.

Até que eu chame um ítem do MenuBar um `JTabbedPane`, fica oculto e assim que é escolhido um ítem de menu, abre-se um Tabbed com jPanel dentro.

Neste jPanel tenho vários componentes, como botões, textfield, jspinner, jlabel, etc.

Acontece que fiz a aplicação programando no meu pc e, ao colocar em rede para outros pcs, a mesma abre não ocupando a tela dos outros monitores, por uma questão de resolução e tamanhos de tela. Vale dizer que apenas o JPnael não abre do tamanho da tela.

Como posso resolver isso de maneira proporcional? Para que nenhum componente fique fora do lugar. Meio que porcentagem?

Answer (score 5):

Para fazer a aplicação abrir maximizada, basta adicionar o trecho seguinte antes do `setVisible()`:

```
seuFrame.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

E para que o `JPanel` se ajuste ao `JFrame`:

```
seuFrame.setContentPane(seuJPanel);
```

Lembrando que, se tiver vários paineis dentro do Frame, você precisa criar um para ser o principal, que irá conter todos eles.

Porém, para que os componentes se ajustem conforme a resolução, você precisa trabalhar com [**Layout Managers**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), eles que são responsáveis pela distribuição de componentes dentro de um [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) qualquer, basta escolher o que melhor atende sua necessidade, ou mesclar vários juntos.

Comment: Obrigado, diegofm. Tentarei aqui adaptar sua ideia. Assim que resolver termino esse post aqui.